# Determining whether a subset of a vector space is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

Studying the book "Linear algebra Done Right, came across this exercise.

I found it is not closed under addition by giving this counterexample. Is it correct?

\begin{aligned}U=\left\{ \left( x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}\right) \in F^{3}:x_{1}+2x_{2}+3x_{3}=0\right\} \\
\left( 0,3,-2\right) \in U\wedge \left( 6,-3,0\right) \in U\\
\left( 0+6,3-3,-2\right) \notin U,\end{aligned}

Comment: The vector $(0, 3, 2)$ is not in $U$.

Comment: How do you get $(0,3,2)\in U$?  Do you mean $(0,3,-2)$?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Just edited.

Comment: @F.Zer, $\left( 6, 0, -2 \right) \in U$. Infact, $U$ is a subspace for $\mathbb{F}^3$.

Comment: No, your example is not correct. That sum actually is in $U$.

Comment: In the future, please enter important parts of your question as text instead of pasting an image of them. Your question should be comprehensible with images disabled. I’d bet that it would take you less time to type in that one sentence and formula than it did to take the picture, crop it, upload it, and link it into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that if $$x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 = 0$$ and $$y_1 + 2y_2 + 3y_3 = 0$$ then we can add both sides of the equations:
$$(x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3) + (y_1 + 2y_2 + 3y_3) = 0 + 0$$
$$(x_1 + y_1) + (2x_2 + 2y_2) + (3x_3 + 3y_3) = 0$$
$$(x_1 + y_1) + 2(x_2 + y_2) + 3(x_3 + y_3)= 0$$